# Database doesn''t recognize String from UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to learn HTTP Connection with Swift, Currently I have this code in my ViewController:

```
func upload_request()
{
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "myLINK.php")!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let data = userEmail.text?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: data, completionHandler:
        {(data,response,error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(dataString)
        }
    );

    task.resume()

}

@IBAction func postToServerButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    upload_request()

}
```

On the server side I have a little PHP code that Echo "Yes There is an Mail" if the server received the userEmail successfully and "No, no email is set"

But I receive "No, no email is set" while I'm specifying that the email is assigned from UITextField !!

When I edit the code and change the "data" value to:

```
"email@gmail.com".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Works fine and I receive "Yes there is an email"

So what is the problem with the TextField text? i'm I manipulating it wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Swift 3 you are supposed to use URL, URLRequest and Data instead of NSURL, NSMutableURLRequest and NSData

Comment: Make sure you pass the whole URL String including the URL scheme

Comment: @LeoDabus When I edited my code as you say, now the Server replies with No, Email in both ways even when I type the string my self. So I think I'm going to stick with the original code

Comment: You need to serialize your Json object data https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you show me how, because I'm still learning HTTP and I don't know how to pass the whole URL

Comment: Json top object should be array or dictionary